# How can I find IPA charts that pairs the phonemes of Japanese with a common word feat. that phoneme in that language?

Tags: resource-request, japanese, ipa

How can I find equivalents to the following chart for Japanese?

Scilicet, the chart for Modern Japanese must SCHEMATICALLY map out each of its phonemes. Each phoneme must be tailgated by a common Modern Japanese word featuring  that phoneme. Vowels MUST be charted in a triangle or quadrilateral. Useless to list out phonemes unordered or unschematic!

[image]

These two pages stem from the 2013 10 edn. of Fromkin, Rodman's *An Introduction to Language*. My library doesn't have the [2018 11 edn](https://www.cengage.com/c/an-introduction-to-language-11e-fromkin/9781337559577PF).

Comment: Hi, could you please focus the IPA question on just one language? Asking for languages generally makes the question too broad (which is actually a close reason on Stack Exchange sites).

Comment: @Tsundoku I narrowed this to Japanese. Please reopen?

Comment: @Tsundoku Thanks, but can you please retain my first para.? Undeniably, it's unproductive if I must ask this question for each e-language. I'm yearning to know the general method to find such IPA charts, that applies for each e-language.